# Getting the values for last date changed and previous date changed in SQL

Tags: sql, date, view, report

I have a data table detailed below which shows all the changes made to a cost on an item.

```
HistoryID   ItemID  Cost  Date          User
---------------------------------------------
136551      2233    120   2017-06-06    Bren
154021      2233    125   2018-01-26    Admin
136552      2251    89    2017-06-06    Bren
154023      2251    95    2018-01-26    Admin
154026      2251    100   2018-01-29    Manager
```

The outcome of the report i would like is to show the value and user of the last change against the value of the previous cost.  And then the discrepancy against this.  Below is the result i would like to see.

```
ItemID   Old Cost   New Cost   Difference  Changed Date   User
--------------------------------------------------------------
2233     120        125        5           2018-01-26     Admin
2251     95         100        5           2018-01-29     Manager
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff suggested please post database and version you are using.

Here is a tsql solution should work with MSSQL 2008+

```
declare @example as table (
    ExampleID int not null primary key clustered
,   ItemID int not null
,   Cost    int not null
,   Date_   date not null
,   User_ nvarchar(25) not null
);

insert into @example (ExampleID, ItemID, Cost, Date_, User_)

select 136551, 2233, 120, '2017-06-06', 'Bren' union all
select 154021, 2233, 125, '2018-01-26', 'Admin' union all
select 136552, 2251, 89,  '2017-06-06', 'Bren' union all
select 154023, 2251, 95,  '2018-01-26', 'Admin' union all
select 154026, 2251, 100, '2018-01-29', 'Manager';

 ;with cte as (
    select ExampleID
         , ItemID
         , Cost
         , Date_
         , User_
         , dense_rank() over(partition by ItemID order by exampleid desc) Ranking
      from @example
                )
    , cte2 as (
    select ItemID 
         , [2] PreviousCost
         , [1] CurrentCost
      from (
                select ItemID
                     , Cost
                     , Ranking
                  from cte
                 where ranking < 3
            ) x
     pivot
                (
                    min(cost) for ranking in ([1], [2])
                ) as pvt
            )

select a.ItemID
     , PreviousCost
     , CurrentCost
     , abs(PreviousCost - CurrentCost) CostDifference
     , Date_
     , User_
  from cte a
  join cte2 b
    on a.ItemID = b.ItemID
 where Ranking = 1
```